# Apache IVY configuration extends pattern

Tags: java, ant, osgi, ivy

In the ivy.xml file is there any way to specify that a configuration extends all other configurations that have names starting with "use_"?

For reference please look at the ivy.xml below:

```
<ivy-module version="2.2" xmlns:o="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/osgi">
    <info organisation="IBM" module="mymodule">
        <extends organisation="bundle" module="mymodule" revision="1.0.0.qualifier" location="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" />
    </info>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="update.dependencies" extends="use_?"/>
        <conf name="compile" extends="default"/>
        <conf name="test" extends="compile" />
    </configurations>
</ivy-module>
```

I need this because I'm trying to make a build script for an OSGi bundle. This means that you specify the location of the manifest (MANIFEST.MF) and IVY will create automatically configurations for each used package specified in the manifest.

Example: use_org.apache.commons.codec.binary

This configuration gets generated because I'm importing the org.apache.commons.codec.binary package.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to solve your problem with the configuration extend mechanism? See https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/extends.html for details.